# Using BizTalk publish a message for nservicebus implemented using SqlServer as transport

Tags: biztalk, nservicebus, biztalk-2010

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Pick up files from various locations using BizTalk
2. Debatch the data
3. Publish a message to NService bus.

The question is how to publish a message to NSB when the **underlying transport for NSB is SqlServer** and not MSMQ?

Comment: -1 already?  I have done some research and I dont see any solutions or pointer

Comment: Are you really looking for each piece of the process, or just the publishing to NServiceBus - points 1 and 2 are relatively basic and lots of details can be found online already.

Comment: Just publishing to NSB.  1,2 are quite straight forward

Comment: Is this blog post any help? http://blog.bitsnbytes.us/2013/08/how-can-i-run-nservicebus-with-sql.html

Comment: Not quite.  NSB is already running using SQL Transport.  Its the BizTalk piece of dropping messages for NSB that I am concerned about. One option that I have is to create a new adapter using NSB - but if I knew how to build the Header and required correlation ID i could just drop the message with these properties into the table using WCF-SQL adapter.

Comment: Maybe Integrating BizTalk Server and nServiceBus
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3125.  <edit> Looks like it only covers MSQM, so probably of no use either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered exposing a Service in NServiceBus as a WCF endpoint? You can then call the WCF endpoint from Biztalk.